# React Infinite scrolling with using API

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

I would like to show each 10 data with infinite scrolling by using yts API. 
It shows that I can show data by this code `https://yts.am/api/v2/list_movies.json?sort_by=download_count&limit=10'`
and it has limit between 1 - 50, but I want to show data infinitely. It seems has page Parameter..
Do you guys have Idea of how can I show data infinitely?

this is the link of yts API
https://yts.am/api#list_movies
[image]

this is my code of call API

```
_getMovies = async()=>{
 const movies = await this._callApi() 
 this.setState({
   movies 
 })
}

  _callApi=()=>{
    return   fetch('https://yts.am/api/v2/list_movies.json?sort_by=download_count&limit=10')
    .then(potato=> potato.json()) 
    .then(json=> json.data.movies)
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea behind infinite scoll is get the N number of records from API.
That N depends on your screen height, so you will have some height to your each item in your list so divide available screenHeight/ height of each item. Now it will give  you some number in N , now take few extra  records like 4-5 so that you will have scroll and now check if scrollTop exceeds the scrollHeight property. and when it goes again the call for next page. Thats it, that's how it works.